# Allow users other than Administrator to view report details

Tags: wordpress, permissions, reports

We are using civi 5.4.1 on Wordpress 4.9.
We want to allow users other than Administrator the ability to view reports and click on the names in the reports to view that contacts details.

Currently if the User searches, they can click on the names with no problems, but if it's a report, they can only view the list, if they click on the name they get the below error message.   Is this a permission issue?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue, although it is a little confusing.   First I gave all permissions to the role and it worked, then I started working back to find out which permission needed to be checked.  It turns out that this one **"CiviCRM: access deleted contacts "** is the one that must be checked for other roles to view the details in a report.   Weird.